# Is there any expression for "it is kind of [troublesome]?

Tags: expressions

Here is the situation.

I always wear short pants when I go to gym. Even if it is really cold outside, I wear short pants, because I will end up changing into short pants if I go to gym in long pants. As such, I always wear short pants when I go to gym.

In this situation, I would like to say 'it is kind of _____.'
Are there any words to express this feeling?

I used to say 'it is kind of troublesome.' But I don't think it is the right expression. Would it be okay if I say 'it is kind of chore'?

Comment: Continuing the sentence with "to ..." can help you find an apt description. "*It is inconvenient to keep changing pants.*" "*It is easier to just use the same pair.*"

Comment: Hi Loy, welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question - please note that not capitalising the pronoun "I" is guaranteed to upset an English language enthusiast (and attract downvotes!). Regarding the word you seek, "chore" is a noun so you'd say "It's kind of a chore", but otherwise it's a perfectly appropriate word to use (although there's nothing wrong with *troublesome* other than it being a bit old-fashioned).

Answer (score 1):

'It is a **pain**.' aka 'It is kind of **pain in the neck**.'

a **pain** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pain)

> 5. Also called pain in the neck, an annoying or troublesome person or thing.

Also ass, arse, butt, rear, depending on context and audience.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same thing pertaining to a lower part of the body.

Answer (score 0):

'It's more trouble than it's worth.'.

For all intents and purposes, it is more trouble to complete the task than the benefits gained completing said task.

Related:

'Digging a hole just to fill it up again.'

Generally referring to a task given to someone by a superior as a method of (not so) subtle punishment. Essentially, a task with no rewards.